# how to scrape for a particular search item?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this [site](http://www.businessdirectoryoman.com/search.php), for a particular search item available under the option "search by category".
But I am not getting a proper site response so I can scrape it, it looks like there is a background call happening.

I have tried setting value as required('for example 10') but it doesn't work.

I want to know how to set category to get the required web page.

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#filename='comp1.csv'
#f=open(filename,'w')
#company=csv.writer(f)


url=requests.get("http://www.businessdirectoryoman.com/search.php").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
links=soup.find_all('div',class_='BdCoTitle')
for i in links:
    print(i.text)
```

```html
<div class="searchcoll">
                <div class="searchcol1">By category
                <select name="searh_category" id="searh_category" style="width: 250px" ;="" onchange="getdat(this.value)">
<option value="0" selected="selected">All Categories</option>
<option value="10">Abrasives</option>
<option value="11">Access Controls &amp; Attendance Systems</option>
<option value="15">Access Platforms</option>
<option value="20">Accommodation &amp; Office Rentals </option>
<option value="0" selected="selected">Accountancy Training</option>
<option value="30">Accountants &amp; Auditors</option>
<option value="40">Acrylic Products</option>
<option value="50">Acu Cure</option>
<option value="60">Adhesives</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="searchcol2">Or by company name:
   <input name="search1" type="text" id="search1" size="55" placeholder="Search for Company">

   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Trying to Get these results(Marked in red)]
**Using Python and Beautiful soup.

Comment: What you had tried so far, please mention that in question. Also additionally please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scrape the `options value/text` from that `select` you provided then you can try this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<div class="searchcoll">
                <div class="searchcol1">By category
                <select name="searh_category" id="searh_category" style="width: 250px" ;="" onchange="getdat(this.value)">
<option value="0" selected="selected">All Categories</option>
<option value="10">Abrasives</option>
<option value="11">Access Controls &amp; Attendance Systems</option>
<option value="15">Access Platforms</option>
<option value="20">Accommodation &amp; Office Rentals </option>
<option value="0" selected="selected">Accountancy Training</option>
<option value="30">Accountants &amp; Auditors</option>
<option value="40">Acrylic Products</option>
<option value="50">Acu Cure</option>
<option value="60">Adhesives</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="searchcol2">Or by company name:
   <input name="search1" type="text" id="search1" size="55" placeholder="Search for Company">

   </div>
</div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

select_option=soup.find("select",{"id":"searh_category"}).find_all("option")
for option in select_option:
   print(option["value"],option.text)
```

Comment: You are saying that they uses ajax to load that data, but no that in loaded using ajax. You can do more research there and grab that from their HTML. I want you to do atleast this, since you hadn't provided any code. I can give you this much answer. @Demonslayer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use next example how to get information from all pages under one category:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = "http://www.businessdirectoryoman.com/search.php?page={}"
data = {"searh_category": "10"}  # <-- category 10 == Abrasives

page = 1

with requests.session() as s:
    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(
            s.post(api_url.format(page), data=data).content, "html.parser"
        )

        titles = soup.select(".BdCoTitle")

        if not titles:
            break

        for title in titles:
            print(title.get_text(strip=True))

        page += 1
```

Prints:

```
Abrasives Manufacturing Co (SAOG)
Al Hassan Group of Companies - Al Hassan Technical & Construction Supplies LLC
Arabian Engineering Services LLC  - Arabian Engg Services (Tyres, Batteries & Allied Prod Div)
Das Investment & Transport Co LLC
Gulf Services & Industrial Supplies Co LLC - Industrial Tools & Equipment
International Automobiles & Parts Co LLC (Parts/Tyres, Battries & Allied Products Div) - International Automobiles & Parts Co LLC (Parts/Tyres, Batteries & Allied Products Div)
Middle East Fuji Khimji’s Co LLC
Suhail Bahwan Group (Holding) LLC - Bahwan Building Materials LLC
Technical Building Materials
Technical Trading Co LLC
```